# Building view hierarchy using relative paths

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and attempting to learn parts of it from the documentation. I was able to create using absolute paths ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdSkh)), but not having any success using relative paths. After I modify the code to

```
App.UserView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'user',

  firstName: "Albert",
  lastName: "Hofmann",

  infoView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'info',

    posts: 25,
    hobbies: "Riding bicycles"
  })
});
```

Ember is not able to find the relative view in the templates. My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkCgU) attempt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/nkCgU/3/

You have to inline children views template parts declaration in the same template block.

Comment: So what is the significance/usage of `templateName` in `infoView` in your implementation since there is really no template named 'info'?

Comment: Sorry! Copy/paste programming from your code snippet... :-/ Apologies. I updated the link.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wasn't really pointing at your jsfiddle alone, since the documentation also has the `templateName` in `infoView`. So it was confusing.